# What is a shadow ceph object? And how is it created?

Tags: ceph

when i run `radosgw-admin gc list`, i see some objects with oid like this `ac7cb16a-c4d4-4e8e-a6ad-97898dc5af11.3801298515.76__shadow_.5zReEt5X65lTn5l8-XgFafxRhgJ6tYe_1`

what is it? And is it dangerous to delete it?

Comment: Those are deleted files that the garbage collection (gc) has not purged yet. Depending on your gc settings it can take a couple of hours until they are deleted.